# Store JSON array as TEXT array in INSERT INTO Postgres statement

Tags: postgresql

Before, I had the following table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    "city_id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "city_name" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "employees_names" JSONB NOT NULL
);
```

I use logstash (jdbc output plugin) to store data in psql. Here is my config (working). As you can see, I need to use the VALUES statement in order to store data.

```
statement => ["
INSERT INTO cities (
    city_name, 
    employees_names
) 
VALUES (
    ?, 
    CAST (? AS JSON)
)
",
"[doc][city_name]",
"[doc][employees_names]"
]
```

The data is stored under the following form. My Json data is just an array.

```
 city_name    |                    employees_names                     
--------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 new_york     | ["marc", "steven", "julia"]
```

Now, I want to store the `employees_names` as a text array (`TEXT[]`) and I want my table to look like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
    "city_id" BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "city_name" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "employees_names" TEXT[] NOT NULL
);
```

As I can't use fonctions (like `json_array_elements_text()`) in the `VALUES` statement, how can I do that ? What would my `INSERT INTO` statement look like ? Thanks !

Comment: That's a bad design. Employees aren't an attribute of a city. This isn't about JSON, storing multiple entities in a single field violates database design rules. What happens when you have to add or remove employees? Or find Julia's city? Move employees from one city to another? What happens if you need to add a *surname* ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! That's not a bad design in my case. The fields names are just examples :)